# How can I know if I should group data on a time series?

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with a time series of 1 year, with power values every 15 minutes. There's an example in the link below concerning only 4 hours.

I want to know if I can group the power values per hour. I think I'd probably do that using a statistical test which could evaluate the similarities.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeD6u.png

Comment: Why do you want to group those values? Do you want to combine it with different time series, is it for computational reasons or for visualization reasons?

Comment: @dimpol yes, it is for computacional reasons. I cannot import my data into R software and even if I could, I don't think I could execute all the procedures.